# The appropriate usage of the API : `/me/taggable_friends`

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

With [v2.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog) in effect, the API `/me/friends` is now limited to the list of friends that have authorized our app. So, this wont help if I need the complete list of my friends.

But facebook also have added a new API [`/me/taggable_friends`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/taggable_friends) that we can use in order to generate stories that have friends tagged in them, even those friends don't use our app. And if we want to use the taggable friends API, the app will require [review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login).

So, before sending for review I want to make sure that **will my app be approved or not?** I'm confused since-

- the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog) says-

  > use in order to generate stories that have friends tagged in them;
- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23417628/1343690) answer by facebook product manager mentioned that-

  > should only be used for the case where you're rendering a list of friends in order to let the user tag them in a post

So I want to know **in which scenarios we can use this API** that complies with its rules and will be approved when sent for review. For using the [OG Actions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/v2.0), of-course it will work (also mentioned in the doc), **but** will it be approved if-

1. the an app is just displaying the list the friends and their profile pics. No story, nothing; or
2. if an app is uploading a photo using [`/me/photos`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/photos) and tagging the selected friends using the `tags` parameter. (there's no info of `tags` parameter in the documentation of `/me/photos` but it exists).

I'm just asking this to make sure that it will be approved or not before making too many changes.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue - people please help!!

Answer (score 0):

The guidelines for OG tagging can be found here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/submission-process#actioncapabilities-actiontagging

Without the context of your action is hard to say if it's acceptable without the user seeing the story and understanding the situation.  If you had a bowling app that allowed people to tag their friends while they were all bowling together And no configurable story and the story generated was something like "Bowling with XXX". I think that would be acceptable...

Attaching a story to your OG Story would be another capability as part of Story configuration.  Tags would apply to the OG story and the photo.

If you want to upload a photo outside of the OG story you need to look at Photo Upload permissions.